# Why is the tag excerpt hidden by default on a tag's main page?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, tag-wiki-excerpt

Whenever I visit a tag info page, I find that the tag-excerpt is hidden by default and there is a link called "show excerpt" at the bottom. Clicking this causes the excerpt to appear at the top.

Why are the tag wiki excerpts hidden by default?

Comment: This seems to no longer be true. Safe to close this one as no longer reproducible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get to a tag info page (other than editing the URL) is by clicking a link `Learn more` that is shown by hovering over a tag (or clicking `Info` on [site].stackexchange.com/tags). This is because it is expected that you land on the tag info page *because you want to know more* about the topic/tag after reading the *short, concise* description (ie. the excerpt).

The main tag wiki should stand by itself - if it needs to refer/rely on the excerpt to make sense, it should be edited to remove that dependence.

There isn't any need to show the excerpt *by default* - it would just be a waste of space, because it is, in effect, useless once you land on that page.

Answer (score 1):

The default info page is the tag wiki, which has more info than the excerpt.

The excerpt is a brief summary of the wiki, so it makes sense to show the wiki by default, which is the full info, rather than the excerpt.

Excerpts are *mainly* used for providing info when you hover over tags around the site, as they are a smaller "summary" of the wiki and so fit better within small pop-up boxes.